# How do i use the Android soft keyboard with an inline DatePicker?

Tags: android, datepicker, android-softkeyboard

I am using Android 2.1(API Level 7) android.widget.DatePicker. The DatePicker widget is inline(i.e. not with the DatePicker dialog).

The DatePicker works fine with the -/+ keys, but not with the soft keyboard to edit the year and press the 'DONE' key on the soft keyboard.